# HELP NEEDED -- Enabling SSH on Rpi with Ubuntu 20.10 without screen

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, 20.10

I am trying out Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 for my Rpi 4 with 8 gb ram. I need to install a certain 'LCD_Show' folder with ssh as the screen I am using will not work without it. I know that adding an file called "ssh" works on Raspbian, but will that work on Ubuntu? A way to overclock the pi on ubuntu would be nice as well.

Comment: I can't specifically speak to Ubuntu 20.10 on a pi, but it's normal for Ubuntu desktop releases to have the `openssh-client` installed (ie. so you can `ssh` to other machines from the desktop), where as Ubuntu server installs to having the `openssh-server` installed too (ie. you can `ssh` **into** the box from elsewhere).  `ssh` I would expect to be installed, but you'll want `openssh-server` rather than the client as you want to use it as a server (ie. use it from a remote machine)

Comment: If you install the Server Edition first you can do it.  See:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview

Comment: the file named `ssh` should work. I have a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04LTS (server) and it worked there. For some better insight you might also want to try [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Also: I don't really understand why you would install Ubuntu DESKTOP when you don't have a screen to see the GUI. The base version (or server version) might be better suited for your needs.

Comment: Almost every question on AskUbuntu is HELP NEEDED. That part of the title is unnecessary.

Comment: user535733, very helpful

Comment: Where should I put the ssh.txt file, totalynotanoob? BTW, I need to install a driver to make the screen work, which is why I must use ssh.

Comment: @TheOrchidomaniac Sorry for the late reply but you should have tagged me with @ that way I would have gotten a notification. You should put a file named `ssh` NOT `ssh.txt` in the boot partition. Although after having installed another RaspberryPi with Ubuntu 20.04LTS I have found that ssh is enabled by default. For more info please read the [Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using same version of Ubuntu Desktop on same model of Rpi (Ubuntu installed on SD card using [rpi-imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/)), it seems ssh client is installed by default but **not** the **ssh server**. This means you can only use ssh from the Rpi to access another remote machine, not to ssh (or use scp) from remote machine to the Rpi. Attempting to use ssh from remote machine to Rpi will return error:

```
ssh: connect to host <Rpi IP address> port 22: Connection refused
```

To install the ssh server on the Rpi do:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

For more details see [How to fix: Connection refused by port 22 Debian/Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/fix_connection_refused_ubuntu/).